# How to install sumneko_lua

Tags: neovim, lsp, lua

I'm a Mac user with complete lua config. I have tried installing `sumneko_lua` in Neovim 0.6.1 several times but without success. Frustration led me to open this question.
I have also read and tried to follow several tutorials but without success.

The [official one](https://github.com/sumneko/lua-language-server/wiki/Build-and-Run) all clear but not the last point: I run in my terminal: `./bin/lua-language-server` with this infinite output:

```
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"$/status/report","params":{"text":"Lua","tooltip":"Cached files: 0/0\nMemory usage: 2M"}}Content-Length: 120

{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"$/status/report","params":{"text":"Lua","tooltip":"Cached files: 0/0\nMemory usage: 1M"}}
```

About the [official setup](https://github.com/neovim/nvim-lspconfig/blob/master/doc/server_configurations.md#sumneko_lua), what it literally means: *The default cmd assumes that the lua-language-server binary can be found in $PATH.* What exactly should I do?

In older tutorials [this](https://jdhao.github.io/2021/08/12/nvim_sumneko_lua_conf/) and [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D9vRBSna7Hs&t=553s) (min 8:30) I found that this line is missing in official config: `cmd = {sumneko_binary_path, "-E", sumneko_root_path .. "/main.lua"};`

Opening a lua file I have this error:

```
Spawning language server with cmd: `lua-language-server` failed. The language server is
either not installed, missing from PATH, or not executable.
Spawning language server with cmd: `lua-language-server` failed. The language server is
either not installed, missing from PATH, or not executable.
```

I also tried to follow these tutorials mentioned above unsuccessfully. The first, it does not solve where and how to use this path `export PATH="$HOME/tools/lua-language-server/bin/macOS:$PATH"`. The second, opening a lua file, manages to start the configuration: not in my setup.

Is there anyone who can clearly indicate all the steps for a correct and complete configuration?

Comment: probably you want to export `PATH` to include the directory that your `lua-language-server` program is in

Comment: put that in an answer, please'

Comment: @D.BenKnoble ok, posted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOLUTION** - If you using [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/) you can install [lua-language-server](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/lua-language-server) with `brew install lua-language-server` and you're done!